# Combobox not visible to code behind in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, json, xaml

I have been trying to add items to a comboxbox but cannot seem to get the code behind file to recognize the combobox added to the xaml.  I am pretty sure I am missing something simple.  Basically the xaml here illustrates an empty combobox.  The code behind executes the service, waits for json to come back and deserialize it.  Unfortunately I cannot get

xaml:

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="Growing.Views.Room" 
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
       d:DesignWidth="950" d:DesignHeight="480"
       Title="Home" Style="{StaticResource PageStyle}" DataContext="{Binding}" xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" ShowGridLines="True" Background="#FF631C00">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Height="298" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="195,94,0,0" Name="rect" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="582" Fill="#FFAAAAAA" RadiusY="0.25" RadiusX="0.25" />
    <sdk:Label Height="38" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="387,160,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="203" Content="Select a Room" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <sdk:Label Height="18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="312,240,0,0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69" Content="Area:" FontSize="14" />
    <ComboBox x:Name="RoomAreas" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="418,235,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="209" />
</Grid>
```

The code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Growing.DataConnectionRef;

namespace Growing.Views
{
    public partial class Room : Page
    {
        public Room()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Asynchronously call the EndReceive Web Service to change the status of an existing open lot record
            WebClient GRService = new WebClient();
            GRService.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(GRService_DownloadStringCompleted);
            GRService.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("/servicestack/GetAreas", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        static void GRService_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Area> dataList = new List<Area>();
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Result));
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new    DataContractJsonSerializer(dataList.GetType());
            dataList = ser.ReadObject(memoryStream) as List<Area>;
            memoryStream.Close();
            RoomAreas.ItemSource = dataList;

        }

    }
}
```

At RoomAreas.ItemSource I get an error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Growing.Views.Room.RoomAreas'`

Sorry if this is hard to follow.  Anyone have any ideas what might be going on here?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make GRService_DownloadStringCompleted method **non static**:

```
void GRService_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<Area> dataList = new List<Area>();
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(e.Result));
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new    DataContractJsonSerializer(dataList.GetType());
            dataList = ser.ReadObject(memoryStream) as List<Area>;
            memoryStream.Close();
            RoomAreas.ItemSource = dataList;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ItemsSource="{Binding}"  to the combobox property within the Xaml